# Apply Ease to Part of Motion Tween

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, cc-2014

I have a motion tween on a symbol where the symbol moves into the scene horizontally, waits awhile, and then moves vertically. In the image below, you can see the animation motion graphed for the tween when it has no easing:

[image: ease correct]

However, I'd like to have the horizontal and vertical movements eased a little bit for a better visual effect. So I click the 'Add Ease' button and add a Simple ease. All of the sudden now, the timing of the motion is way off! Notice how the vertical movement happens *much* before it should actually happen in the second image (as pointed to by the yellow arrow):

[image: ease bad]

What's the best way to deal with this issue? The ease should apply to the segments with motion but not to the segments without motion. I'd rather not have to break this up into multiple tweens, but if necessary that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no easy way to do this. Your best bet, as you alluded to, is to right-click the tween where the first part of the motion ends and choose 'Split Motions'. Also split the tween where the second motion starts. You can then apply an ease to the now separate tween segments as necessary.